# failed to process /proc/version_signature

Tags: canonical, ubuntu-advantage

I started a docker container and then installed ubuntu-advantage-tools in the container, although had following error messages during the installation, i assume it does not matter.

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34 /usr/share/perl/5.34 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
```

After that, i can get following commands run correctly:

```
# pro --version
27.11.2~22.04.1
```

```
# uname -a
Linux c67b17708016 4.12.14-120-default #1 SMP Thu Nov 7 16:39:09 UTC 2019 (fd9dc36) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
# dpkg -l | grep advantage
ii  ubuntu-advantage-tools      27.11.2~22.04.1                         amd64        management tools for Ubuntu Advantage
```

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
root@c67b17708016:/# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

***However***, other more commands with following exceptions:

```
# pro --help
WARNING:root:failed to process /proc/version_signature.
```

```
# cat /proc/version_signature
cat: /proc/version_signature: No such file or directory
```

```
# pro security-status
failed to process /proc/version_signature.
```

Looks like the kernel failed to launch the pro client somehow.

Anyone met same problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438996/edit) your question and add the output of `cat /proc/version_signature`?

Comment: Thank you for comments. The output is `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Add the output of `uname -a` as well, please. Use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for commands and command output.

Comment: `4.12.14-120-default` doesn't look like any current Ubuntu kernel. Ah, I see you're doing this in a container. Then the kernel is shared with the host, so it seems the only thing to do here if you really need UA in a container (why, though?) is to run in an Ubuntu host.

Comment: @muru Oh... I see, then the reason here is that ***the kernel is shared with the host***.  I just want to taste the UA and unable to find a Ubuntu hosted machine, so I've thought to test UA in a container.

Comment: i managed to get a ubuntu hosted machine, this time i got following problem:

`# pro --help   
Failed to access URL: https://contracts.canonical.com/v1/resources?architecture=amd64&kernel=5.15.0-52-generic&series=jammy  
Cannot verify certificate of server  
Please check your openssl configuration.  `  

how to resolve it?

Comment: @jake You need to make sure that you have an Ubuntu One account and then you need to get your tokens from your account that will install the certs with it as well.  Once you have your account the dashboard will show you your token.  https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard  and there it should show you the command you run to attach that system to pro.

Comment: @Terrance I've already received one token. As I mentioned in above comment, I got the error with command `#pro --help`, I assume failure of this command indicates something wrong which blocks me moving forward (i.e. `#pro atach [token]` etc) the next step,  this error must be resolved. Now, i tried more other command like `#pro security-status` , same failure message shown. Again, i tried `#pro attach [my token i received]`, the error message is `Failed to attach machine. See https://ubuntu.com/pro` ( as i supposed though).

Comment: Are you using an LTS installation?  Also, is your kernel one that either comes with the LTS release or one of the HWE?  Anything outside of those you will not be able to attach the system to pro.

Comment: @Terrance Yes I am using an LTS installation as `cat /etc/os-release` shows following information `PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"  VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"`; And also, `uname -r` cmd shows `5.15.0-52-generic` thus I assume the kernel version is fine to support UA.